# How to run spring boot app in Eclipse tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application and want to run this as a server app within Eclipse.
So the app will be recognized as a Tomcat web app and can be added I update the facet :

[image]

When I run the web app my rest services are not being found. A spring boot app contains a different folder structure than spring apps before spring boot was released. Can a spring boot app be run from an eclipse configured tomcat ? Also prior to spring boot the controllers section of the app needs to specified. Do I need to update my spring boot app with these settings in order to run from Eclipse tomcat ?

I don't want to create a war and then copy it to webapps folder of tomcat.

Update : The reason to run this app within Eclipse tomcat container is that I have other non spring boot applications that my new spring boot app will depend on.

Comment: Just run the app you don't need to deploy it.

Comment: @M.Deinum please see update

Comment: And why would you need to deploy it to tomcat for... Assuming you are using http to communicate that doesn't matter if it is the same tomcat or not. If you want to deploy to tomcat you need a war (this is explained in the reference guide).

Comment: @M.Deinum  it does matter when making rest calls, say I have two apps. a -> spring app . b -> spring boot app. a is making service calls to b. In prod a and b are required to be deployed on same tomcat container. When developing I need to run two instances of tomcat, embedded for a and Eclipse tomcat for b. This also means a or b will need to be run on a different port and and rest calls from a to b will require a port number change.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you use spring boot embedded tomcat you dont need a war.

Comment: @blue-sky Did you include `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency? If you have that you dont need any set up.

Comment: @Jason Z yes, this is not my issue, spring boot app runs fine as a single app. Issues arise when have to to deploy spring boot app and 'plain' spring app within single server container

Comment: Then as stated make it a war, which is explained in the reference guide. @JasonZ I know how spring boot works quite well.

Comment: @M. Deinum making it a war will not enable running the app from Eclipse tomcat. Making a war will just allow the app to be run from tomcat standalone

Comment: It has to be a war to be deployed to any tomcat, the packaging has to be a war. Only changing stuff in eclipse isn't going to help you need to change the packing. How to create a war with spring boot for deployment is explained in the reference guide... So only updating the facet and expecting it to run is obviously not enough (and again I suggest [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) and [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the guides, I'm not concerned with packaging the app , im just concerned with running spring and spring boot applications within same tomcat Eclipse container. Eclipse tomcat will not recognize a spring boot application as a web app without major changes to it's structure.

Comment: Then that is the fault of eclipse tomcat... If it is a war it is a web application. Also the structure is the same so I don't see how it is different (apart from it being servlet 3.0 which doesn't require a web.xml).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then check your main app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then configure Project Facets (as you have already did):

- Dynamic Web Module
- Java
- Javascript

Then check your Deployment Assembly:
[image]

Done!

Comment: this helped me a lot. thank you so much.
but what about the static resources like css,js etc how to make them accessible in this scenario??

Comment: thank you very much, I inherited the project, hence that I didn't even know that I had to manually add Maven Dependencies to the Deployment Assembly

Comment: Adding the "Maven Dependencies" under "Deployment Assembly" is what did it for me - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

- use gradle plugins: `eclipse-wtp` and `war`
- extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` in `Application`

### Explanation:

In order to run a spring boot application on tomcat generally the produced artifact has to be a `war` application.

In order to make it run on tomcat inside Eclipse you have to use a WTP-Project (Web Tools Platform aka Dynamic Web Module) using the `eclipse-wtp` gradle plugin.

The `SpringBootServletInitializer` thing has to be extended in order to make Spring Boot application context launch when Tomcat is launched.

## How to create a test project

Spring offers a [Getting Started Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) how to build a REST webservice with Spring Boot. I enhanced the project to work with Tomcat and Eclipse:

### Check out

the sample project:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service.git
```

### Import it into eclipse

Import the `complete/` subfolder as gradle project.

### Change `build.gradle`

remove

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

add

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

### Change `src/main/java/hello/Application.java`

add extension of `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    ...
}
```

That done I could deploy the sample project to a Tomcat server configured in eclipse and start the server. The url is: http://localhost:8080/complete/greeting?name=User

Check out the [Complete Sample](https://github.com/rasenderhase/gs-rest-service).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are unable to see "Deployment Assembly" option, adding below nature to the .project file will enable the deployment assembly option.

org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature

After defining the packing structure for my project, I am able to run the application on Tomcat server without copying the war file in webapps directory manually.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this annotation in the main class of spring boot.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value={"packages name to scan"})
```

Add dependence in `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this 2 simple steps and your good to go!

Step 1. Change packaging format to war instead of jar in your pom.xml file.

```
     **<packaging>war</packaging>**
```

Step 2. Right click on your project then do Maven -> update project.

After doing this steps you will find an option to "Run on server" when you try to run your project.